# Is a Windows Server CAL needed for IEEE 802.1x MAC authentication bypass?

Tags: windows-server-2012, nps

We want to deploy IEEE 802.1X port-based authentication for specific devices by means of MAC authentication bypass. For this, we must enter the MAC address of the device as username and password in the Active Directory for NPS on Windows Server 2016 that acts as RADIUS server.

My question is: do the required user accounts for MAC authentication bypass count as separate CALs?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need need so-called "Device CALs". See:

https://community.hpe.com/t5/Alliances/Understanding-Windows-Server-Client-Access-Licenses-CALs/ba-p/7001696#.XYywJC2B1Bw

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/client-access-license